# Python code that updates YouTube thumbnails every 10 minutes, fails after about an hour - do I need to use refresh tokens?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, thumbnails, refresh-token, video-thumbnails

So, earlier today, I started a YouTube experiment that involves updating the thumbnail image every 10 minutes. So, I based my Python code off of a code sample from the Google Developers page on youtube.thumbnails.set(): https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set

My code looks like this:

```
def doCredentialStuff():
    global youtube
    global flow
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console(access_type='offline')
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

def updateYTthumb(filename):
    try:
        request = youtube.thumbnails().set(
            videoId=VIDEO_ID_UPLOAD,media_body=MediaFileUpload(filename))
        response = request.execute()
        print(response)
    except Exception as exc:
        print("ERROR!!!! I got this exception: "+str(exc)+" at time "+str(time.time()))
```

For my purposes, I want to upload thumbnails every 10 minutes. So, I run doCredentials() only once, at the start of running the code. Then, every 10 minutes, I re-run updateYTthumb(), where it actually executes the request. (This part)

It works perfectly for anywhere from 2 to 12 iterations! (20 - 120 minutes). However, if I let it sit for long enough, it always eventually returns this error:

```
 [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I'm not sure how to fix this:

- Should I get a refresh token somewhere in `doCredentialStuff()`, and then use it during `updateYTthumb()`?

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that something on your computer interrupted the connection, here are a few things you can try:

- Updating your google-api-python-client
- Disabling your antivirus
- Disabling your firewall

Answer (score 0):

try using crontab to do such timely operation.

Answer (score 0):

The base doc w.r.t. authorization is [OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps).

This doc [specifies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#exchange-authorization-code) that upon the OAuth flow, you receive a *short-lived* access token and a *long-lived* refresh token.

The section [Calling Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#callinganapi) specifies that with access tokens one may issue API calls that require authorization (like yours is). The section [Refreshing an access token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline) specifies that access tokens expire periodically.

Consequently, you have to trade with the API for a fresh access token each and every time the current one becomes invalid (i.e. expired), using the refresh token you received earlier (which does not expire at all -- except for when it is [explicitly revoked](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#tokenrevoke) by the user).